# Bold a section of Text in a DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to be able to bold a portion of a dropdownlist item. I want to bold the License_Name of this ListItem;

```
   Dim newListItem As ListItem

   newListItem = New ListItem(Reader("License_Name") + " - " + Reader("City") + " " + Reader("License_Nbr"), Reader("License_Nbr"))
   ddlEstablishment.Items.Add(newListItem)
```

I tried adding <'b'> before and <'/b'> after and all it does is display the codes <'b'> and <'/b'> in the list. Minus the single quotes.

Comment: That is because server encode strings from codebehind, so they are not 'treated' as html. You have to define or inject css to the control.

Comment: Ok, so how do I do that for just a portion of the string then?